# How to pre-configure the AWS CLI on an EC2 using Boto3 and UserData

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto

Using the Boto3 Python SDK for the AWSCLI I can set up spot instances using the following lines of code:

```
ec2 = b3.client('ec2')
spot_request = ec2.request_spot_instances(
    InstanceCount=1,
    LaunchSpecification={
        "ImageId": "ami-******",
        "KeyName": "*****",
        "SecurityGroupIds": ["*****"],
        "UserData": config_64_encode,
        "InstanceType": "t1.micro"},
    Type='one-time'
)
```

The instances launch fine however the UserData parameter does not work!

In this case the user data is just an AWS configure file (ec2_config.sh) but I’d like to pre install python packages in the future.

```
#!/bin/bash
aws configure set aws_access_key_id **************37YQ
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key ******************B1TBsOh
aws configure set default.region eu-west-1
aws configure set default.output json
```

Boto3 requires that the configuration file is encoded as Base64, which I 
do using the following lines of code:

```
config = open(ec2_configure,"rb")
config_read = config.read()
config_64_encode = base64.b64encode(config_read).decode('ascii')
```

I know the encoding is correct as I get the same result when exporting the ec2 configuration from the AWS console.

Could it be that the AMI doesn’t allow for UserData? Or have i made a mistake somewhere else?

Cheers

Comment: Try to cat /var/log/cloud-init-output.log you should find there the reason your UserData is not being set up properly. Btw I think a better way of achieving what you are trying to do is assign a role with pre-configured permissions to the instances you want to launch so you don&#39;t need to use UserData. I don't remember if AMIs come out by default with awscli installed but I think no and there could be your problem

Comment: And more important using roles you don't have to pass credentials in clear text around

Comment: as mentioned in above comments passing role would be better ,  You need to set the IamInstanceProfile under LaunchSpecifications.

Comment: Thanks both, however when i ssh into the instance I cannot find the cloud-init-output.log file / the /var/log/ directory doesn't exist